# Frameles and transparent Window does not work! Qt widget

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm  using Qt widget.

I needed a dialog that shows when I click on a button on my main window that dialog should be transparent meaning if I opened it I still can see the background like there's nothing there.

I tried this in the constructor of my dialog:

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground,true);
this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
```

- Note: I'm using mouse events where I can get the coordinates of the mouse and I tried it and it's working, the only thing I want now is as I said the transparent part.
  The program compiles just fine and the icon displays in the bar where the programs that are open are there , but I can't use the events which I can see if the I deleted the code above.

To make it more clear here's the mouse events:

```
void FramelessWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    if(event->button()==Qt::LeftButton){
           origin= event->pos();
           rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin,QSize()));
           rubberBand->show();
    }
}

void FramelessWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin,event->pos()).normalized());
}


void FramelessWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event){   
    rubberBand->hide();
}
```

*Edit:

After spending nearly 12 hours trying to figure out how to solve this , I just couldn't :( I tried everything but it doesn't work , hopefully there's another method to do the same thing ? i'm on windows 8..

*Edit 2:

Yeah I'm using windows 8..

And what I meant about " used everything " is that I've done everything in google, tried this guy's method:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/42406/

and this guy:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53362-Qt5-Translucent-alpha-channel-problems

still it didn't work...

..

ok is there another method to grab the mouse events ? where for example the user can press and drag and then release and I get the coordinates so I can take pictures and stuff like that , the user needs to see the background , that's why I said it needs to be transparent.

Comment: sorry but I didn't get it, how ?

Comment: @BЈовић: he is using Windows 8.

Comment: @user3622289: `I tried everything but it doesn't work` -> perhaps you could elaborate what everything means?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Qt 5.2 you may like to have a look at this Qt Windows Extras:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwinextras-overview.html